# Is the stationarity property invariant by transformation?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

In other words, if $X_t$ is $I(0)$, is $f(X_t)$ also $I(0)$?

I would say yes:

- The mean stays constant.
- The autocovariance still depends only on the lag between the terms.

Comment: You have not defined or restricted $f$ in any way. For an arbitrary $f$, why should the mean stay constant or the ACF only depend on the lag between the terms?

Answer (score 1):

1. You will at least need strict stationarity, because even in the $X_t$ all have the same mean (and variance), the distributions can be different and so the $f(X_t)$ does not necessarily have the same mean if $f$ is nonlinear.
2. So then assume strict stationarity, then the answer becomes **yes** for marginal transformations $f$. That is really a consequence of the well-known result that $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E f(X) = \inf f(x) \; dF(x)$, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).
3. For a question about the converse see [If the square of a time series is stationary, is the original time series stationary?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408023/if-the-square-of-a-time-series-is-stationary-is-the-original-time-series-statio)